# Extend displaytag with struts 1. Problem in keeping current page and sort condition

Tags: java, jsp, displaytag, struts-1

I am implement displaytag by extend the standard. Please see detail below.

*JSP*

```
display:table name="testList" id="obj" requestURI="testAction.do?pageAction=init" pagesize="${paging_size}" sort="list" class="table" **sort="external"** excludedParams="*" decorator="dyndecorator" export="false" **keepStatus="true"** 

  display:setProperty name="pagination.pagenumber.param" value="page" 
  display:setProperty name="pagination.sort.param" value="sort" /
  display:setProperty name="pagination.sortdirection.param" value="dir" 

  display:column property="testNo" title="Test no." **sortable="true"** **sortName="testNo"** 

  display:column property="testValue" title="Test value" **sortable="true"** **sortName="testValue"** 
display:table
```

*PaginatedListImpl*

```
public PaginatedListImpl(HttpServletRequest request) {
 sortCriterion = request.getParameter("sort");
 sortDirection = "desc".equals(request.getParameter("dir"))? SortOrderEnum.DESCENDING : SortOrderEnum.ASCENDING;
 pageSize = DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE;
 String page = request.getParameter("page");
 index = page == null? 0 : Integer.parseInt(page) - 1;
}
```

JAVA

```
public PaginatedListImpl getTest(
 Criteria criList = session.createCriteria(TestDto.class);
 criList.setFirstResult(pageDisplay.getFirstRecordIndex());
 criList.setMaxResults(pageDisplay.getObjectsPerPage());
 pageDisplay.setList(criList.list());
 pageDisplay.setTotal((Integer) criTotal.uniqueResult());
 return pageDisplay;
}
```

**Anyway, I found problem on browser** when the browser render the result

1. when I move the mouse over page_no. It will show "http://localhost:8080/WebProject/testAction.do?**page=2**&pageAction=init"
2. when I move the mouse over column name. It will show "http://localhost:8080/WebProject/testAction.do?**sort=testValue**&**dir=asc**pageAction=init"

but **I need the link of both** like this
"http://localhost:8080/WebProject/testAction.do?**page=2&sort=testValue&dir=asc**&pageAction=init"

I search on google many time but I still have a problem.

How can I do? Someone Please help me out of problem.

Thank you a lot..

Comment: has any source inside your question?

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you my sample code below

```
<%
 String str = "/details.do?method=showQuestions&surveyId="+arrayNew.get(0);
%>

<html:link page='<%=str%>'><%=arrayNew.get(1)%></html:link>
```

Try to put url in string variable and use the string variable in the html:link tag as shown above. This may solve your problem.

Thanks